# Unable to import list into MySQL - Python, Tweepy & MySQL.Connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector, tweepy

I have written the following code. I am so close to getting it to work, I can almost taste and smell it.

I am using mysql.connector, tweepy, python 3.2 and the xampp stack. I am creating a unique table to hold the last 3200 tweets from a user. I'm running it in a loop and I can get all the results to print to screen; absolutely no problem at all. The problem arises when I try to write to a MYSQL db. The table creates fine, as do the columns.

EDIT:

After assistance from @Yarkee and @bernie, I've edited it to the following:

```
tweet_created_date = str(tweet.created_at)
list = [tweet.id, tweet.text, tweet_created_date,
                    tweet.geo, tweet.contributors, tweet.coordinates,
                    tweet.favorited, tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name,
                    tweet.in_reply_to_status_id, tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str,
                    tweet.in_reply_to_user_id, tweet.in_reply_to_user_id_str,
                    tweet.place, tweet.retweeted, tweet.retweet_count,
                    tweet.source, tweet.truncated]
sql = ("""INSERT INTO %(table_name)s (tweet_id, tweet_text,
    tweet_created_at, tweet_geo, tweet_contributors,
    tweet_coordinates, tweet_favorited,
    tweet_in_reply_to_screen_name, tweet_in_reply_to_status_id,
    tweet_in_reply_to_status_id_str, tweet_in_reply_to_user_id,
    tweet_in_reply_to_user_id_str, tweet_place,
    tweet_retweeted, tweet_retweet_count, tweet_source,
    tweet_truncated) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,
    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""" % dict(table_name=table_name))
cursor.execute(sql, list)
```

I've now got a `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your database table look like?

Comment: see updated question.. I've added the code used to create it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQLdb uses the `%s` paramstyle, e.g.: `(%s,%s,%s)`. It does NOT use the `?` paramstyle. Reference: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Comment: your sql clause is end with "VALUES(?,?,?,?,...,?)" mysqldb doesn't suppport this format. It should be "VALUES(%s,%s,%s,...,%s)"

Comment: I've edited the original question. I've now got another error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `'%s'` as `'%%s'`.

```
>>> '%(a)s, %s, %s' % dict(a='x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
>>> '%(a)s, %%s, %%s' % dict(a='x')
'x, %s, %s'
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on. You are a legend!

Answer (score 0):

Final code is as follows. The table name is generated separately and uniquely from a combination of the current unix time value and the user's screen name.

```
    tweet_list = [tweet.id, tweet.text, tweet.created_at, tweet.geo, 
    tweet.contributors, tweet.coordinates, tweet.favorited, 
    tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name, tweet.in_reply_to_status_id, 
    tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str, tweet.in_reply_to_user_id, 
    tweet.in_reply_to_user_id_str, tweet.place, tweet.retweeted, tweet.retweet_count, 
    tweet.source, tweet.truncated]

    sql = ("""insert into %(table_name)s (tweet_id, tweet_text,
    tweet_created_at, tweet_geo, tweet_contributors, tweet_coordinates,
    tweet_favorited, tweet_in_reply_to_screen_name,
    tweet_in_reply_to_status_id, tweet_in_reply_to_status_id_str,
    tweet_in_reply_to_user_id, tweet_in_reply_to_user_id_str,
    tweet_place, tweet_retweeted, tweet_retweet_count, 
    tweet_source, tweet_truncated) VALUES (%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,
    %%s,%%s,%%s,%%s, %%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s,%%s)""" 
    % dict(table_name=table_name))

    cursor.execute(sql, tweet_list)
```

Thank you so much for all that have assisted and I hope that this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Glad I could help.

It's good etiquette to accept an answer. Probably Yarkee's since he answered your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3 (or even Python 2.6 or 2.7), you should take advantage of string.format(). Using a bit more simplified example, to show how to use it:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(database='test')
cur = cnx.cursor()

stmt = "INSERT INTO {table} (c1) VALUES (%s)".format(
    table='t1'
) 
data = ('ham',)
cur.execute(stmt, data)
cnx.commit()
```

With format() you don't have to escape the %s parameter markers. (Note that I'm using MySQL Connector/Python, which was used in the original question.)